# what variables can we use for the if statements in the generic preseed file

Tags: maas

i see we can user if statements in preseed file for maas

```
{{if node.architecture in {'i386/generic', 'amd64/generic'} }}
d-i     mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
d-i     mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
{{else}}
d-i     mirror/http/hostname string ports.ubuntu.com
d-i     mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu-ports
{{endif}}
```

and i want to know if its also possible to use such if statements with tags
so if a node has a tag raid5

that the raid 5 partman code is used

and is there some documentation where we can find on what variables we can use
like node.tags or node.memory

Comment: is this what you want: http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/development/preseeds.html ?

Comment: its a shot in the right direction thanks.
but as i read you can only use "per-architecture, OS release and node name"
it would be great if you can do this based on tags